# error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with about **10 csv** file and I am trying to put them all together. the file in question is the Airbnb listings file from January 2018 to January 2019.  here is my code :

```
for counter, file in enumerate(glob.glob("listings*")) :
     namedf = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows =0, usecols = all, low_memory = False, engine = None)
     results = results.append(namedf)

results.to_csv('C:/filelistings.csv, low_memory = False, engine = None)
```

Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Comment: Please can u share the error code.

Comment: the error code is the following: error tokenizing.C error: out of memory

Comment: Just add it to the question.

Comment: Why set `low_memory=False` if you're out of memory?  Set it to True!

Comment: Thanks, I did that and replace the missing value but the errors come back

Comment: There are too many rows in the files. What exactly is the purpose of the exercise? If all you want is to concatenate the files, use a CSV reader/writer and read/write them one row at a time.